# CreditRisk+ spreadsheet implementation

Tags: credit-risk, default-probability, default-risk, credit-scoring

I'm looking for an Excel spreadsheet where the [CreditRisk+](http://medvegyev.uni-corvinus.hu/creditrisk.pdf) model is implemented by means of a simple toy example, like the one the linked paper is referring to. If that spreadsheet is unavailable, I would be grateful if you could provide a simple toy example in `R` or `Python`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this on waybackmachine:
https://web.archive.org/web/20000817021426/http://www.csfb.com/creditrisk/